# Console error in medium insert js plugin

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

I am trying to integrate medium insert plugin(https://github.com/orthes/medium-editor-insert-plugin). I have set it up according to the instructions. Everything works fine except it is giving me the error in the console when i hover over the + button as:

[image]

I have not made anything to the example code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem.
Since i downloaded the plugin directly from the git repo and installed its dependency using bower, it pulled all the latest plugins and it turns out the latest plugin for **medium-editor(ie. v5.21)** is not compatible with the current latest version of **medium-insert plugin(ie v2.x)**. So i downloaded v5.9 of it(medium-editor) and voila it worked.